# Update list to include new elements of another list (primefactor computation)

Tags: python, list

I am calculating the prime factors for all numbers contained in a list `numbers`. They are returned from my helper-method `primefactors_of_number` as a list. I want to keep track of all of them (e.g. in a list `all_factors` and have them in the correct quantity).

As an example, for the input

```python
[12,16,17]
```

`find_all_primefactors` should return

```python
[2,2,3,2,2,17]
```

in any order.

The point that makes me problems is to update `all_factors` to contain 2 only four times.

Here is my code so far:

```python
def find_all_primefactors(list_with_numbers):
    prime_factors = []
    all_factors = []
    for number in list_with_numbers:
        prime_factors = primefactors_of_number(number)
        # missing part:
        # Update all_factors in a way that it contains all elements of prime_factors at least in the same quantity

    return all_factors

def primefactors_of_number(number):
    ''' 
    Returns all primefactors of the specified number as a list
    '''
    i=2
    prime_factors=[]
    while i<=number:
        while number%i==0:
            prime_factors.append(i)
            number/=i
        i+=1
    return prime_factors
```

I think I could solve this with a lot of looping and temporary values, but I assume there is probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: Sorry for the bad title - I really could not formulate the problem better (which might also cause this to be a duplicate, even though I thoroughly searched for a solution). Please feel free to improve!

Comment: What output are you getting? Where's your code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but you might be looking for [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) (as opposed to `list.append`). So maybe something along the lines of `for n in in numbers: all_factors.extend(prime_factors(n))`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're running that displays the behaviour, and provide test cases (e.g. input and expected and actual output).

Comment: @timgeb I don´t get any output at all yet, because I am missing the function of how to update the list accordingly. I added some code to illustrate what I am doing.

Comment: @LukasGraf good guess!

Comment: @Paul you don't need to "initialise" `prime_factors` in `find_all_primefactors`; that just creates an empty list that never gets used.

Comment: @LukasGraf I am not sure if I understand it entirely, but I think that doesn´t check for earlier occurences of the numbers. For example after processing 12, `all_factors` should contain `[2,2,3]` (corrected that in the question, btw). After processing 16, it should be `[2,2,3,2,2]` and NOT `[2,2,3,2,2,2,2]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks. I run into an error earlier when I tried to `.append` to a non-existing list, so I just went to initializing them all, but since it´s an assignment here it´s of no use.

Comment: @Paul your approach may need to be altered. Try a dictionary, where keys are factors and values are the largest number needed (e.g. `{3: 1, 2: 4}` in your comment example). You can make a list from it later.

Comment: are you sure the output is not supposed to be `[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 17]`? I have a solution for that.

Comment: @timgeb As stated in the question, I don´t care about the order. I forgot the 3 in the original question though, but have edited it in now. So `[2,2,2,2,3,17]` would be as well as `[2,2,3,2,2,17]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks again :) This looks interesting and like what I am needing. I will have a look into dictionaries.

Comment: @Paul no problem. `collections.Counter`, a subclass of `dict`, will help simplify.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think your approach also merits an answer. I tried it successfully to learn something about dictionaries, if you don´t want to make it an answer I would do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion how you could modify your first function:

```
def find_all_primefactors(list_with_numbers):
    all_factors = []
    for number in list_with_numbers:
        prime_factors = primefactors_of_number(number)
        for x in set(prime_factors): # loop over factors without duplicates
            in_all = all_factors.count(x) # how many x are already in all_factors
            in_p = prime_factors.count(x) # how many x are in prime_factors
            diff = in_p - in_all                
            all_factors.extend([x]*diff) # extend all_factors based on difference
                                         # note that [x]*diff is [] for diff <= 0
    return all_factors
```

`primefactors_of_number` stays the same. Output for

```
print(find_all_primefactors([12,16,17]))
```

is

```
[2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 17]
```

Comment: @Paul the `if diff > 0` part was not needed, I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be to first compute the least common multiple of the list of numbers, and then factorize that single number:

```
from fractions import gcd

def find_all_primefactors(list_with_numbers):
    lcm = reduce(lambda a, b: a * b / gcd(a, b), list_with_numbers)
    return primefactors_of_number(lcm)
```

Comment: Thats a nice approach, thanks for sharing it. Actually I am calculating the lcm of `list_of_numbers`, but I didn´t know the formula using the gcd.

Comment: Somehow my edit was declined, so I would like to add for everybody using python3.x that reduce() was removed. use a loop or functools.reduce() instead.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of something like:

```
from collections import Counter

def find_all_primefactors(list_with_numbers):
    all_factors = {}
    for number in list_with_numbers:
        all_factors |= Counter(primefactors_of_number(number))
    return all_factors
```

Comment: You can combine two `Counter` instances using the `|` operator to get the maximum count for each item.  If you initialise `all_factors` to the empty `Counter` object, all you need in the loop body is `all_factors |= Counter(primefactors_of_number(number))`.